# Grocery crud : How to get the current id that had been used when editing and viewing a record?

Tags: grocery-crud

How to get the current id that had been used when editing and viewing a record?

I am currently following the instruction by Alfonso Secas that he posted in this topic..

http://www.grocerycrud.com/forums/topic/1326-how-to-use-grocery-crud-and-image-crud-together/page-2

And now on the part where he said "When editing a record, get the current ID from `$this->getStateInfo();` to compose the iframe's source url."

It seems like `getStateInfo` doesn't exist yet so it shows an error "Fatal error: Call to undefined method `Examples::getStateInfo()` "

Answer (score 0):

http://www.grocerycrud.com/documentation/options_functions/getState

this will do what u want . give it a try

u need to use the CRUD object to call this function instead of $this ..

Answer (score 0):

You have some options:

Primary key
`getStateInfo()->get_primary_key`

Last uri segment
`end($this->uri->segments)`

Does not work in list action.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can use one of CodeIgniter's methods to get id from page url
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/uri.html

You need to take last segment from URI

```
    $segmentsCount = $this->uri->total_segments(); 
    $itemID = intval($this->uri->segment($segmentsCount));
```

p.s. it is not best solution but it can do the trick